# vSphere Linux cannot connect to internet

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vsphere

I am new to virtual machine, Linux and vSphere(just start learning this few week)

I can’t connect the virtual machine (linux) to the internet from the beginning till now. I think the issue is cause by vSphere setting or Linux configuration.

(1) This is how I try to connect the internet and it return a error at the end. Is this error related to DHCP?

After boot up, I run `nmcli device`, it return:

```
DEVICE | TYPE | STATE | CONNECTION
ens192 | ethernet | connecting (getting IP configuration) | ens192
lo | loopback | unmanaged | --
```

Ten minutes later, I run `nmcli device` again , it return:

```
DEVICE | TYPE | STATE | CONNECTION
ens192 | ethernet | disconnected | --
lo | loopback | unmanaged | --
```

Then, I run `nmcli device connect ens192`, it return error message:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).
```

(2) Virtual Hardware Setting: 'Network adapter 1' drop down box is blank. Is that normal?
vsphere screen cap:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you are not connected to any network.
You added a network adapter to you machine (imagine adding a network card to your pc) but did no connected a network to it (plugging in a network cable).

Select a network from that dropdown, and you should be ready to go.